# natural language query using ravendb/lucene

Tags: lucene, ravendb

Take a list of "zoo" documents in ravendb, each of which have a field for year established and a field for description.  Description is a string which will, amongst other information, include many of the animals that can be seen at that zoo.

(1) How can I take a user search value of "chimpanzees AND orangutans OR "great apes" NOT lemurs" and search zoos for descriptions.

(2) How can I do the same search but for all zoos established within 10 years of 1920.

(3) How can I do the following proximity search: "chimpanzees orangutans"~3 AND elephants.

For the purposes of this question, don't worry about singular or plural forms of the animal names.  Assume that they will be plural.

EDIT: I would expect the following test to return zero results, and instead it returns two:

```
    public void LuceneANDQuery()
    {
        var zoosToCreate = new List<Zoo>
                               {
                                   new Zoo()
                                       {
                                           Description = "We have alligators, orangutans and chimpanzees",
                                           AbbreviatedState = "DC"
                                       },
                                   new Zoo()
                                       {Description = "We have orangutans and elephants", AbbreviatedState = "CA"}
                               };
        using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            zoosToCreate.ForEach(session.Store);
            session.SaveChanges();
            new DescriptionIndex().Execute(documentStore);
            string searchPhrase = @"lizards && orangutans";
            var matchingZoos = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Zoo>("DescriptionIndex").Search("Description", searchPhrase).
                WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow().ToList();
            int matchingZoosCount = matchingZoos.Count;
            Assert.AreEqual(matchingZoosCount, 0);
        }
    }

    public class DescriptionIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Zoo>
    {
        public DescriptionIndex()
        {
            Map = zoos => from zoo in zoos
                          select new {zoo.Description};
            Analyzers.Add(z => z.Description, "Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer");
            Indexes.Add(z => z.Description, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balazs,
You can literally just run this query. RavenDB uses Lucene under the cover, and it expose its query outward.
That means that you can just run queries like that. This is exposed in the API using Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery.

One thing to note is that we don't support a default field, so you need to specify what field you mean, but that is about it.

Comment: Except that I can't quite get it to work.  Please see my test above.  I would expect it to return zero results, while it instead returns both zoos.

Comment: Per Oren's response elsewhere:

This isn't an AND search. This is:

  string searchPhrase = @"Description:lizards AND Description:orangutans";
  var matchingZoos = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Zoo>("DescriptionIndex").Where(searchPhrase).